# MS-Access 2010 DateAdd function not displaying data on report

Tags: dateadd

I have the following formula in a field on my form:

=DateAdd("d",5-Weekday([TestDate]+5,2),[TestDate]+5)

It's purpose is to display the date in the "Estimated Date for Completion" field whenever a date is input into the "Test Date" field.  The formula does display the date; however when I generate a report the Estimated Date for Completion" field is blank although it shows a date in the field from the data entry form view.

How can I get the "Estimated Date for Completion" field to print what's displayed in it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a report with just the [TestDate] control. In design view add a textbox control to the report. Open the expression builder for the Control Source and copy/paste your formula as above.

Comment: Thank you Dave.  Although the field now displays text it is NOT the date  calculated based off of the Test Date field.  The formula displays the data results on my form BUT not in my table.  How do I get the Estimated Date for Completion field to generate/display the date information in the table as a result of date info entered the Test Date field.  Although I took an Access class, I'm still learning.  Your  assistance is greatly appreciated.